# Android screen Pinning blocking bluetooth pairing request dialog from popping up

Tags: android, performance

I am working on Android 5.0 above.I have enabled Screen Pinning option programmatically.

My app communicates with a bluetooth device.So when i try to connect to particular bluetooth device i will be prompted with a Bluetooth pairing request dialog,the user will have to enter the pin for connecting.

But when we Screen Pin our particular app and try to connect to the bluetooth device,It is not popping up the pairing request dialog.

Did anyone of you face this situation.If so can you please describe the procedure to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some source code

Comment: Hiii @unicorn2..                                                                                           -So here is my code using this im doing screen pinning.                  
                             

   
-if(!am.isInLockTaskMode()) 
{ 
 startLockTask();
}




-And for creating bond i am calling this:




-if (bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) 
{
 device.createBond();
 device.setPin(BtUtil.convertPinToBytes(name.substring(name.length() - 6)));     
 device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
 return false;
}